Why is the API method for statistics not accessible?
Why is https://api.unix.stackexchange.com/1.1/stats not accessible?

I assume you're looking for this method? That endpoint is no longer supported, we're already at version 2.3 of the API and the URL scheme is quite different nowadays.
Similar information (here is a question documenting the old output) is now available via the /info method:

